# Linux echo append find command output into log file

Tags: linux, find, echo

I would like to know is there any way to show the message with "echo function" + "find command" output into log file?

Current:

/mnt/backup/XXXX/Daily/Logs/20210326.log

Code:

```
logfile=$(date +"%Y%m%d")
find /mnt/backup/XXXX/Daily/Logs -type f -name "*.log" -mtime +6 -print -exec rm {} \; >> /mnt/backup/XXXX/Daily/Logs/$logfile.log
```

Expected result:

**Deleted file -** /mnt/backup/XXXX/Daily/Logs/20210326.log

*Remark: **Bold text** is belong to echo function. Normal text is belong to find command.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a second -exec and so:

```
find /mnt/backup/XXXX/Daily/Logs -type f -name "*.log" -mtime +6 -print -exec rm {} \; -exec echo 'Deleted file - {}' >> /mnt/backup/XXXX/Daily/Logs/$logfile.log \;
```